# Problem debugging legacy Python 2.7 project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I have a legacy console application written in Python 2.7. I have to implement minor changes in it therefore I would like to debug it in Visual Studio 2017. Without the Visual Studio debugger the application just runs fine.

When I run the project under VS2017 debugger, it fails with error:

```
TypeError: <module 'abcdef' from '[...]\abcdef.pyc'> is not JSON serializable
```

This error completely freezes the Visual Studio UI. The only option left is to kill the Visual Studio process in Task Manager.

Here is my question. Is it possible to avoid this issue without changing the code causing it? Is there some magic setting in Visual Studio that could make the debugger happy and let me continue debugging the application?

Below is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\wrapper.py", line 1254, in done
    fut.result()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\futures.py", line 40, in result
    reraise(self._exc_info)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\futures.py", line 155, in callback
    x = it.send(fut.result())
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\wrapper.py", line 1608, in on_stackTrace
    module = self.modules_mgr.add_or_get_from_path(norm_path)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\wrapper.py", line 618, in add_or_get_from_path
    self.proc.send_event('module', reason='new', module=module)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\ipcjson.py", line 279, in send_event
    body=kwargs,
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\ipcjson.py", line 103, in _send
    content = json.dumps(payload).encode('utf-8')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 244, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <module 'abcdef' from '[...]\abcdef.pyc'> is not JSON serializable
```

**UPD SOLVED!** Recently I found an option in VS2017/VS2019, see the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8F7d.png . Setting this option ON in combination with deleting *.pyc files solved my problem. It is interesting that after the first successful run of the project in debugger it is possible to set this option OFF - project debugging remains possible!

Comment: I would try removing the `.pyc` files

Comment: I did it, but the issue still exists. The error is now
TypeError: <module 'abcdef' from '[...]\abcdef.py'> is not JSON serializable

Comment: Hi, same issue when you create a new same-kind project in vs?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!
Recreating the same kind of project helped! There is no error anymore!

Comment: @Lance Li-MSFT, unfortunately, I can't rate your answer as I don't have a reputation on this site yet.

Comment: Mystically, after a couple of successful runs of the recreated project in VS2017 debugger, this error appears again. Deleting the *.pyc files and/or the .vs directory doesn't help.

Comment: Not sure what caused this issue, since it works well for several times before it fails in a new project,I think some changes may result in it. Could you share a simple sample which help reproduce the same issue so that I can check it directly(one-drive or github).

Comment: @Lance Li-MSFT The problem solved, the initial post updated.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the useful info! You can consider adding it as answer :)